# Assets with multiple content types duplicating values

Tags: kademi

When adding additional content type tag on an existing asset it duplicates the values in the fields.

What I am trying to achieve:
There are trainers on NZ site and some of them also goes on AUS site.
So I have created a content type "trainersNZ" which applies to all NZ trainers. Some of them that needs to go on AUS site so I created another content type "trainerAUS" and applied both content types to the same asset but now there is duplication issue.

Screenshot attached below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p36ltk4k9ufo8vv/Screen%20Shot%202019-08-05%20at%201.00.14%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would have a content type structure where your fields only appear on one type.

Eg have a content type called "trainer" which has the appropriate fields, and then have marker types for trainerAu and trainerNz. All assets would have the trainer type, and just tag assets onto the appropriate au/nz types as needed.

However, I've pushed an update so if there are duplicate field names the input will only be shown once on the management page, so you might find that you can continue with the current structure.